# PyQt - system crash when I shift to the third window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am a beginner of using PyQt. I want to build a simple system with PyQt which can shift to different windows when clicking the button. But the system always crashes when shifting to the third window. And return the mistake like this

> ****Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)*****

I have tried to change the type of different windows to make them different with prior one (QDialog→QWidget QWidget→QDialog), but this method didn't make sense.

Hope someone can help me to figure out this problem.

Here is an example code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class FirstWindow(QWidget):

    close_signal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.btn = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn.setText("click")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close_signal.emit()
        self.close()


class SecondWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(150, 150)
        self.btn2 = QToolButton(self)
        self.btn2.setText("click")

class ThirdWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FirstWindow()
    s = SecondWindow()

    ex.show()
    ex.btn.clicked.connect(s.show)
    s.btn2.clicked.connect(ThirdWindow.show)
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: The problem is caused because you want to open a window that you have not created, ThirdWindow is a class, an abstraction, what you must do is create an object similar to what you have done with the FirstWindow and SecondWindow classes: `ex = FirstWindow ()
     s = SecondWindow ()` in your case it could be: `t = ThirdWindow ()`,

Comment: [cont] another error is that the ThirdWindow class is calling the parent's constructor incorrectly `class ThirdWindow (QDialog):
     def __init __(self, parent = None):
         super (**SecondWindow**, self).__init__(parent)`, it should be: `class ThirdWindow (QDialog):
     def __init __(self, parent = None):
         super (ThirdWindow, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: I recommend running it in the cmd since you will get a clear error message: **TypeError: show (self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'
Aborted (core dumped)**

Answer (score 0):

you didn't created an instance of your third class, use this adjustment:

```
App = QApplication(sys.argv)
first = FirstWindow()
second = SecondWindow()
third = ThirdWindow() # this line was added

first.show()
first.btn.clicked.connect(second.show)
second.btn2.clicked.connect(third.show)
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

---

<sub>btw: your `handle_close` is never called</sub>